# Jupyterlab AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter restart failed

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I use python to learn deeplearning, I installed jupyterlab with pip and it works well, one day, it suddenly does not work and throws error like bellow:

```bash
(torch) PS C:\Users\Administrator> jupyter lab
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:37.041 ServerApp] Package jupyterlab took 0.0000s to import
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:37.119 ServerApp] Package jupyter_lsp took 0.0767s to import
[W 2023-06-17 14:50:37.119 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in jupyter_lsp. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:37.150 ServerApp] Package jupyter_server_terminals took 0.0342s to import
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:37.150 ServerApp] Package notebook_shim took 0.0000s to import
[W 2023-06-17 14:50:37.150 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in notebook_shim. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:37.150 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:37.166 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:37.182 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.092 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.190 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.190 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.190 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.206 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.206 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.206 LabApp] Extension Manager is 'pypi'.
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.206 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.206 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: D:/
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.206 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.6.0 is running at:
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.206 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/lab?token=aa7034ecc56dfbb627eadbc8d851c30bffba822f7f228eaa
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.206 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=aa7034ecc56dfbb627eadbc8d851c30bffba822f7f228eaa
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:38.206 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2023-06-17 14:50:39.165 ServerApp]

    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-12908-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/lab?token=aa7034ecc56dfbb627eadbc8d851c30bffba822f7f228eaa
        http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=aa7034ecc56dfbb627eadbc8d851c30bffba822f7f228eaa
[W 2023-06-17 14:50:39.253 ServerApp] Could not determine npm prefix: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:40.107 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, python-lsp-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:43.691 LabApp] Build is up to date
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:44.190 ServerApp] New terminal with automatic name: 1
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:44.884 ServerApp] Kernel started: 71678a6d-6122-49ab-a2c6-2815e8f4a08c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\comm\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\comm\comm.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 70, in <module>
    class Kernel(SingletonConfigurable):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 80, in Kernel
    processes: t.Dict[str, psutil.Process] = {}
AttributeError: module 'psutil' has no attribute 'Process'
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:50.883 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\comm\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\comm\comm.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 70, in <module>
    class Kernel(SingletonConfigurable):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 80, in Kernel
    processes: t.Dict[str, psutil.Process] = {}
AttributeError: module 'psutil' has no attribute 'Process'
[I 2023-06-17 14:50:56.912 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\comm\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\comm\comm.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 70, in <module>
    class Kernel(SingletonConfigurable):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 80, in Kernel
    processes: t.Dict[str, psutil.Process] = {}
AttributeError: module 'psutil' has no attribute 'Process'
[I 2023-06-17 14:51:02.968 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\comm\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\comm\comm.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 70, in <module>
    class Kernel(SingletonConfigurable):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 80, in Kernel
    processes: t.Dict[str, psutil.Process] = {}
AttributeError: module 'psutil' has no attribute 'Process'
[I 2023-06-17 14:51:09.014 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\comm\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\comm\comm.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 70, in <module>
    class Kernel(SingletonConfigurable):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 80, in Kernel
    processes: t.Dict[str, psutil.Process] = {}
AttributeError: module 'psutil' has no attribute 'Process'
[I 2023-06-17 14:51:15.021 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (5/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\comm\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\comm\comm.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 70, in <module>
    class Kernel(SingletonConfigurable):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 80, in Kernel
    processes: t.Dict[str, psutil.Process] = {}
AttributeError: module 'psutil' has no attribute 'Process'
[W 2023-06-17 14:51:21.042 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 2023-06-17 14:51:21.042 ServerApp] Kernel 71678a6d-6122-49ab-a2c6-2815e8f4a08c died, removing from map.
[W 2023-06-17 14:51:44.923 ServerApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 71678a6d-6122-49ab-a2c6-2815e8f4a08c
[E 2023-06-17 14:51:44.923 ServerApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/71678a6d-6122-49ab-a2c6-2815e8f4a08c/channels?session_id=b2a9aaee-509d-48e9-9e8f-69f7f08b2cda (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/71678a6d-6122-49ab-a2c6-2815e8f4a08c/channels?session_id=b2a9aaee-509d-48e9-9e8f-69f7f08b2cda', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1786, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\websocket.py", line 65, in get
        await super().get(kernel_id=kernel_id)
      File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 272, in get
        await self.ws_connection.accept_connection(self)
      File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 862, in accept_connection
        await self._accept_connection(handler)
      File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 902, in _accept_connection
        self.selected_subprotocol = handler.select_subprotocol(subprotocols)
      File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\websocket.py", line 87, in select_subprotocol
        preferred_protocol = self.connection.kernel_ws_protocol
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel_ws_protocol'
[E 2023-06-17 14:51:44.939 ServerApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.51"
    }
[E 2023-06-17 14:51:44.948 ServerApp] 500 GET /api/kernels/71678a6d-6122-49ab-a2c6-2815e8f4a08c/channels?session_id=b2a9aaee-509d-48e9-9e8f-69f7f08b2cda (dfdb52a93fe74c88adc58852455ea6c6@::1) 60026.44ms referer=None
[W 2023-06-17 14:51:45.265 ServerApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 71678a6d-6122-49ab-a2c6-2815e8f4a08c
[E 2023-06-17 14:51:45.265 ServerApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/71678a6d-6122-49ab-a2c6-2815e8f4a08c/channels?session_id=e5a80dff-0bbd-4153-95ab-80b2f106f9af (127.0.0.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/71678a6d-6122-49ab-a2c6-2815e8f4a08c/channels?session_id=e5a80dff-0bbd-4153-95ab-80b2f106f9af', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1786, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\websocket.py", line 65, in get
        await super().get(kernel_id=kernel_id)
      File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 272, in get
        await self.ws_connection.accept_connection(self)
      File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 862, in accept_connection
        await self._accept_connection(handler)
      File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 902, in _accept_connection
        self.selected_subprotocol = handler.select_subprotocol(subprotocols)
      File "D:\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\websocket.py", line 87, in select_subprotocol
        preferred_protocol = self.connection.kernel_ws_protocol
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel_ws_protocol'
[E 2023-06-17 14:51:45.265 ServerApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.51"
    }
[E 2023-06-17 14:51:45.265 ServerApp] 500 GET /api/kernels/71678a6d-6122-49ab-a2c6-2815e8f4a08c/channels?session_id=e5a80dff-0bbd-4153-95ab-80b2f106f9af (dfdb52a93fe74c88adc58852455ea6c6@127.0.0.1) 60009.14ms referer=None
```

I look into the error message and find that this exception may be caused by the `nodejs`, I reinstall this module using command `conda install -c conda-forge nodejs`, but this can not solve this problem， please help me how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I fixed this problem by reinstall the jupyterlab after uninstalling it.

```bash
pip uninstall -y jupyterlab
pip uninstall -y jupyterlab-pygments
pip uninstall -y jupyter-console
pip uninstall -y jupyterlab-server
pip uninstall -y jupyterlab-widgets


pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyterlab
```

the jupyterlab components may be different with yours, you just uninstall yourselfs.

Comment: Finally, these commends worked for me after trying various other uninstall & reinstall.